# convolution on 2 by 2 matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-number-theory, numerical-linear-algebra

Let $m$ be a positive integer, and let $A_1,B_1 \in \operatorname{SL}(2,\mathbb{Z})$. Can one always find matrices  $A_2,B_2 \in \operatorname{SL}(2,\mathbb{Z})$ such that
$$
A_1 \left( \begin{array}{cc}
m^{-1} & 0  \\
0& m\end{array} \right)B_1 =A_2 \left( \begin{array}{cc}
m & 0  \\
0& m^{-1}\end{array} \right)B_2 
$$
PS: $\operatorname{SL}(2,\mathbb{Z})$ are the set of all $2\times 2$ matrices $A$ with entries in $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\det(A)=1$.

Many thanks.

Comment: Why is the question posed as it is? Once you've got an answer for $A_1=B_1=I_2$, the general case easily follows.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
let
$J= \left( \begin{array}{cc}
0 & 1  \\
-1& 0\end{array} \right)$. Note that $J^2=-I$ and $$J \left( \begin{array}{cc}
m^{-1} & 0  \\
0& m\end{array} \right)(-J)= \left( \begin{array}{cc}
m & 0  \\
0& m^{-1}\end{array} \right)$$